# How to support an old flag name when changing to a new flag name with Cobra?

Tags: go-cobra

I have a CLI with a flag name that I would like to rename, but I would also like to make it so this change is backwards compatible and using the old flag name still works, such as below:

```
# New flag name
root subcommand --no-color

# Old flag name still works
root subcommand --nocolour
```

My original thought with this was to alias the flag name to the new name as described [here](https://github.com/spf13/pflag#mutating-or-normalizing-flag-names). This approach does change the flag name to the new name, but it does not make it so you can use the old name of a flag as well.

I have put in place an approach to solve this by defining another flag with the same properties but a different name and also moving the shorthands to the new flag, such as below:

```golang
// Old flag name
cmd.PersistentFlags().BoolP(
    "nocolour", "", false,
    "disable colouring (default: false)")

// New flag name
cmd.PersistentFlags().BoolP(
    "no-color", "C", false,
    "disable coloring (default: false)")
```

And then I mark the old name flag as hidden:

```golang
cmd.PersistentFlags().MarkHidden("nocolour")
```

I am wondering if there is a way to accomplish what I did above without having to define and support two flags?

Answer (score 2):

I used the `SetNormalizeFunc` function provided by cobra to do rename a old flag value to a new one.

```
func addFlags() {
    // Define a new flag `ignore-var-run` and use the same variable opts.IgnoreVarRun to capture the flag value.
    RootCmd.PersistentFlags().BoolVarP(&opts.IgnoreVarRun, "ignore-var-run", "", true, "Ignore /var/run directory when taking image snapshot. Set it to false to preserve /var/run/ in destination image. (Default true).")
    
    // Keep the old flag `whitelist-var-run` as is.
    RootCmd.PersistentFlags().BoolVarP(&opts.IgnoreVarRun, "whitelist-var-run", "", true, "Ignore /var/run directory when taking image snapshot. Set it to false to preserve /var/run/ in destination image. (Default true).")
    
    // Mark the old flag as deprecated. 
    RootCmd.PersistentFlags().MarkDeprecated("whitelist-var-run", "please use ignore-var-run instead.")

    // SetNormalize function to translate the use of `whitelist-var-run` to `ignore-var-run`
    RootCmd.PersistentFlags().SetNormalizeFunc(normalizeWhitelistVarRun)
}

func normalizeWhitelistVarRun(f *pflag.FlagSet, name string) pflag.NormalizedName {
    switch name {
    case "whitelist-var-run":
        name = "ignore-var-run"
        break
    }
    return pflag.NormalizedName(name)
}
```

Here is the PR for this https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/pull/1668/